# May I end a sentence with "between the two", or must I use a pronoun, "between them" or "between the two of them"?

Tags: grammaticality, sentence-structure

The case in point is:

> If we need to think about a module while we design another, then this
>   characterizes a dependency, even if there is no direct connection
>   between the two.

Is this grammatically correct? Do I need to change the sentence to end it with "between the two of them" or "between them"?

Comment: It's fine - ***the** two* is correctly used here to refer back to two things previously mentioned (***a module*** and ***another*** [module]).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Numerals can be used where nouns are expected:

> "The needs of the many outweigh the needs of the few, or ***the one***."

You don't *need* to add "of them" after "the two".

Answer (score 5):

This construction is quite common and perfectly acceptable.

Earlier in the sentence, however, the *a* should be replaced with *one*:

> If we need to think about <s>a</s> **one** module while we design another ...

*One ... another* is the standard way of distinguishing two determinate-but-unspecified entities: we are enjoined to *Love one another*, and we say that *One good turn deserves another*.

Comment: I'm not too sure about that *"a" **should** be replaced with "one"*. It *could* be, and stylistically you might prefer that, but I wouldn't put it so strong. Truth to tell, your version *wouldn't* sit so well with me in this exact context, because in practical terms the primary focus must be on the module we're actually *designing*. It kinda jars with me to reference that one with the "vague" determiner ***another*** while simultaneously referencing the ***one*** we're "incidentally" thinking about with a highly specific determiner.

Comment: That's to say, if I wanted to use the standard ***one...another*** pairing, I'd prefer *If while we design **one** module we need to think about **another**, then this characterizes a dependency, even if there is no direct connection between the two.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers Hmm ... I agree that your sentence is better; but I disagree about *one* being "highly specific". I'd call *one* not a "specific" determiner but the stressed form of *a/an* (which is an inversion of the historical fact, but you know what I mean).

Comment: I like *stressed form of **a*** for the specific usage we're talking about here (sod the etymology). But to my mind even though it strongly implies ***no particular** one* in terms of *which one we've started talking about*, the "stressed" form also strongly implies that we're intending to focus on that specific one in subsequent text. So I can say *If **one** explanation is simpler than another, **it** should be the preferred choice* - in the sure and certain knowledge that you'll connect ***it*** to ***one***, not ***another***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Da. But I suspect that's a function of ordering and stress, not 'oneness'. "If this is simpler than that, it should be preferred" will have the same implicature; and in both the implicature can be cancelled.